# Inherit @PreAuthorize annotation with custom annotation for spring custom method security expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, annotations

I have successfully implemented a Custom Method Security expression in my Spring Boot project.

Here is my expression root:

```java
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

    public boolean checkTwoParamsAreEqual(Long param1, Long param2){
        return param1.equals(param2);
    }

    //constructor and overridden methods ignored for brevity

}
```

*All other required configuration and handlers for method security expression is implemented correctly.*

Inside my controller class, I did:

```java
@GetMapping("/test")
@PreAuthorize("checkTwoParamsAreEqual(#id1, #id2)")
public String tst( @RequestParam("id1") Long id1, @RequestParam("id2") Long id2){
   return "Voila!!!";
}
```

With this, when I make get request with the same value for `id1` and `id2` request params, it returns `Voila!!!`, and for different request parameter values, it throws 403 exception. This is exactly what I want.

---

Now, I want to optimize my above code by using a custom annotation class for `@PreAuthorize`.

My custom annotation is defined as:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Inherited
@PreAuthorize("checkTwoParamsAreEqual(#id1, #id2)")
public @interface PreCheckParamsAreEqual {
}
```

And, I updated my controller by:

```java
@GetMapping("/test")
@PreCheckParamsAreEqual
public String tst( @RequestParam("id1") Long id1, @RequestParam("id2") Long id2){
   return "Voila!!!";
}
```

With this change, no matter what values I pass for request parameters `id1` and `id2`, they always return "Voila!!!". I could not figure out a way on how I can create a custom annotation with parameters.

Comment: There appears to be a typo, at least in the code snippet. In your custom annotation, it says `@PreAuthorize("checkTwoParamsAreEqual(#id1, #id1)")` which is sending `id1` into both parameters.

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that. it's just the issue with the code snippet here. I have updated it. With this corrected, the issue still remains the same.